# Is there a single word for both good and bad news?

Tags: single-word-requests

How can you combine good and bad news together into one word?  Good and bad news in the sense that a physician would say, "I have both good and bad news."

Comment: What's wrong with "I have news"?

Comment: The simple answer is obviously "news". But in this example I think you are looking to stress that there is both good and bad news. I think a doctor would say simply "There is both good and bad news...".

Comment: Consider "contrasting news".

Answer (score 6):

[WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/heart/news/20160614/mixed-news-on-drinking-and-heart-health#1) itself uses "mixed news"

The title of the referenced article reads:

> Mixed News on Drinking and Heart Health

I've heard it often in other contexts indicating that there is both good and bad news, but cannot find any other citations offhand.